# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).carouFredSel is not a function [Wordpress plugin]

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The plugin works but Chrome sends an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs6Fv.png)

Here is the code:

```
    $slider_gallery .= '
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var wa_vars = ' . $data_json_str . ";

$('#wa_chpcs_foo' + wa_vars.id).carouFredSel({ . . .
```

I tried using jQuery instead of $ but it still returns the same error.
I also tried other answers here but to no avail.
I can't use another plugin since this is the only one approved by my supervisors to use.
Any idea as to how this can be solved?